# Right curly bracket around text

Tags: matrices, brackets, braces

The following code will produce some text enclosed by a right curly bracket and to the right of it some other text saying that is the same meaning.

Now, I would like to have the text aligned to the left and with the same font as the one outside the bracket.

How can I do that? I red a lot but the solution is still far.

```
\begin{document}
\section{TITLE}
SUBTITLE
Line1, some text.\\
$\left.\begin{matrix}
- some text some text some text some text\\
- some text some text some text some text some text\\
- some text some text\\
\end{matrix}\right\}$
they are the same
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `tabular` also in math mode. So

```
$\left.\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
- some text some text some text some text\\
- some text some text some text some text some text\\
- some text some text
\end{tabular}\right\}$
```

will work. However, it's better to define your own environment:

```
\newenvironment{rightbracedtext}
 {$\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\left.\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}}
 {\end{tabular}\right\}$}
```

Thus you can type

```
\begin{rightbracedtext}
- some text some text some text some text\\
- some text some text some text some text some text\\
- some text some text
\end{rightbracedtext}
```

A `tabular` in math mode will use inside it the font which was current outside math mode. The `\kern-\nulldelimiterspace` is an adjustment to remove the space inserted by `\left.`.